# HTML - Wrap current tag inside another tag

Tags: filetype-html

I'm editing an HTML file, and my cursor is inside a tag, like this:

```
<textarea class="code-area"></textarea>
```

And I'm trying to wrap all of this tag inside a `div` tag, so that it'd be like this:

```
<div>
    <textarea class="code-area"></textarea>
</div>
```

I can use [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and type `yss<div>`, but it'll change it into this:

```
  <div><textarea id="code-area"></textarea></div>
```

How can I wrap it so that it adds newlines as well?

Also, the `yss<div>` command only wraps the current line. I'm interested in wrapping an entire tag, no matter how many lines it has.

Comment: Does `ySat<div>` fit?

Comment: @Matt Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) `ys{motion}` puts "a surround text" on the same line. To place it on a line of its own with indent you should use `yS{motion}` instead.

Next, a motion you want for this case is `:h at` (a tag). So this results in <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

Answer (score 3):

As you are surrounding single line you `VS<div>`

Let's break it down:

- `V` enter visual by line select mode
- `S` surround with...
- `<div>`

Your    <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>    <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd><</kbd>    <kbd>d</kbd>        <kbd>i</kbd>    <kbd>v</kbd>    <kbd>></kbd>

command didn't work as third letter which is <kbd>s</kbd> is something like  **substitute**  surrounding, while we want something like **append** <kbd>a</kbd> some **tag** <kbd>t</kbd>, as in @Matt's answer.

By the way, your <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>    <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd><</kbd>    <kbd>d</kbd>        <kbd>i</kbd>    <kbd>v</kbd>    <kbd>></kbd>
way useful while typing this answer for surrounding letters of `yss<div>` with `<kbd>` tag to look them like buttons.

Credit go to official [Vim Surround Docs](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).